# Bash - how to evaluate curly brackets wildcard from a variable

Tags: bash, unix

Lets say I write a command in unix bash:

```
[~/mm]$ ls log{1,2}
```

It matches 2 files:

```
log1  log2
```

But when I store the curly brackets in a variable:

```
[~/mm]$ x=log{1,2}
```

And execute this:

```
[~/mm]$ ls $x
ls: cannot access log{1,2}: No such file or directory
```

The log{1,2} are not expanded to log1 | log2, instead the exact file name is matched.

How can I run the command with evaluating the curly brackets in the variable?

Comment: Use an array, In bash brace expansion happens before variables do.

Comment: Or use .... `eval`